# Weighted cross-entropy tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, cross-entropy, numerical-stability

I couldn't find a tensorflow built-in that allows you to pass in labels which don't sum to 1, so tried writing my own: (Input is [batch_size,labels])

```
tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(y_true,axis=1) * tf.reduce_logsumexp(y_pred_logits,axis=1)
 - tf.reduce_sum(y_true * y_pred_logits,axis=1))
```

However it doesn't seem to be working (loss is diverging). Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think it was correct, but I set the "epsilon" of Adam optimizer too low.